# Ubuntu 16.10: Selenium grid client not connecting to Selenium grid server

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have started hub and node like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -role hub &
java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.40.40:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig /opt/selenium/defaultNodeConfig.json -browser "browserName=chrome,platform=LINUX" &
```

and this is my /opt/selenium/defaultNodeConfig.json:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "platform": "LINUX",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "cleanSession": true,
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "/opt/selenium/geckodriver",
            "webdriver.firefox.bin": "/usr/bin/firefox"
        },
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "platform": "LINUX",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "/opt/selenium/chromedriver"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start Selenium client to connect to hub like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp ".:/opt/selenium/client-combined-3.5.3-nodeps.jar:/opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar" de.auticon.selenium_server.Grid_SetUp
```

with Grid_SetUp.java being:

```
package de.auticon.selenium_server;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;    
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Grid_SetUp {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[]  args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/opt/selenium/chromedriver");

        String URL = "http://www.google.com";    
        String Node = "http://192.168.40.40:4444/wd/hub";    
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
        driver.navigate().to(URL);    
        Thread.sleep(5000);    
        driver.quit();    
    }       

}
```

I get the error:

`leder@leder-VirtualBox:~/Source/SeleniumCheese/bin$ ./execute_grid.sh 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: host: 'leder-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.0-59-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown`

Connecting with the same java client to the same java hub and node on windows works fine!

Is there something wrong with my `chromedriver_linux64` integration in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I additionally had to use java option -D like this for chromedriver:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/opt/selenium/chromedriver -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.40.40:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig /opt/selenium/defaultNodeConfig.json -browser "browserName=chrome,platform=LINUX" &`